# WAN ip address looks like private ip, but whatsmyip shows a public ip address

Tags: router, ip, wan, port-forwarding, modem

Let me preface this by saying that I'm not very good with internet networking, but I tried my best to gather information. So I've been meaning to do some port forwarding to open a server, but I got stuck on this IP issue. The wan IP address has a private IP address (which should be public) so I cant get the server working (works on localhost, not with IP)

The WAN IP looks like this and is in the range of 192.168

[image]

When I logged into my modem, it shows me something like this (it looks like the modem is giving the router the private IP)

[image]

Finally, when I go into my modem, it shows the IP is static and somewhat different from the one in the router (still in 192.168 range). Also, my whatsmyip IP address is 78.84.....

Is this an ISP issue? Can it be fixed if I contact them? Or perhaps the modem is not recognizing my router as a router and giving it the wrong IP address.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Apparently, your ISP is not connecting your with a public IP address directly and using CG-NAT instead. However, networks not under your control and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].